# Get webpage contents with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.1, if that helps.

Anyways, I'm trying to get the contents of [this](http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/ranking?table=0&category_type=0&time_filter=0&date=1519066080774&user=zezima) webpage. I Googled for a little bit and tried different things, but they didn't work. I'm guessing that this should be an easy task, but...I can't get it. :/.

Results of urllib, urllib2:

```
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
ImportError: No module named urllib2
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
>>>
```

## Python 3 solution

Thank you, Jason. :D.

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/ranking?table=0&category_type=0&time_filter=0&date=1519066080774&user=zezima')
print(page.read())
```

Comment: Duplicate:  Search for `urlib2` or `get web page [python]` in SO and you'll find 100's of similar questions.

Comment: Tried urllib2 and urllib, but neither worked. (Edited first post)

Comment: He's using Python 3, so the APIs are different. I surely learned something new by researching this answer.

Comment: @Andrew: It helps to check the questions and answers carefully to see if they say Python 3 or not.  If they don't say Python 3, they don't apply to you.

Comment: For anyone looking for python 2, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2289768/79125 (use urllib.urlopen)

Comment: The accepted answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because you're using Python 3.1, you need to use the new [Python 3.1 APIs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html).

Try:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
```

Alternately, it looks like you're working from Python 2 examples. Write it in Python 2, then use the 2to3 tool to convert it. On Windows, 2to3.py is in \python31\tools\scripts. Can someone else point out where to find 2to3.py on other platforms?

**Edit**

These days, I write Python 2 and 3 compatible code by using six.

```
from six.moves import urllib
urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
```

Assuming you have six installed, that runs on both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I'm on Windows. Anyways, thanks, it worked fine. (The page you linked me to looks very helpful, by the way. Thanks for that, especially.)

Comment: On Ubuntu, it was in the path, so I just had to run the `2to3` command. Whereis says it is at `/usr/bin/2to3`

Comment: Damn, python 3 is starting to become a problem: one can't just copy-paste the first stack overflow answer and expect it to work anymore !

Comment: @xApple: The way I see it, Python 2 is starting to become a problem ;)

Comment: Using 'six' is a good idea if your code must work under both python 2 and python 3. This is only the case if you are writing a library to be used by others (and even then, caring about python2 is less and less common,) If you are writing executable scripts or applications, especially for your own use, you can just pick one of python3 or python2, and use it exclusively, free of the complications 'six' introduces.

Answer (score 61):

If you're writing a project which installs packages from PyPI, then the best and most common library to do this is [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). It provides lots of convenient but powerful features. Use it like this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=zezima')
print (response.status_code)
print (response.content)
```

But if your project does not install its own dependencies, i.e. is limited to things built-in to the standard library, then you should consult one of the other answers.

Answer (score 9):

If you ask me. try this one

```
import urllib2
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=zezima')
```

and read the normal way ie

```
page = resp.read()
```

Good luck though

Answer (score 5):

[Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is a great package for "acting like a browser", if you want to handle cookie state, etc.

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Answer (score 2):

You can use urlib2 and parse the HTML yourself.

Or try **Beautiful Soup** to do some of the parsing for you.

Comment: Tried urllib2 and urllib, but neither worked. (Edited first post)

Comment: Andrew, others can help you better if you describe in detail what you tried and what error message(s) / unexpected behaviour resulted.

Comment: I edited it into my initial post because I didn't want a huge comment. :P.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [faster_than_requests](https://pypi.org/project/faster-than-requests/) package. That's very fast and simple:

```
import faster_than_requests as r
content = r.get2str("http://test.com/")
```

Look at this comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with works with Python 2.X and Python 3.X:

```
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=zezima'
response = urlopen(url)
data = str(response.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to GET a webpage's content. The following code does it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# python

# example of getting a web page

from urllib import urlopen
print urlopen("http://xahlee.info/python/python_index.html").read()
```