# Python and urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to download a zip file ("tl_2008_01001_edges.zip") from an ftp [census](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/01_ALABAMA/01001_Autauga_County/) site using urllib. What form is the zip file in when I get it and how do I save it?

I'm fairly new to Python and don't understand how urllib works.

This is my attempt:

```
import urllib, sys

zip_file = urllib.urlretrieve("ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/01_ALABAMA/Autauga_County/", "tl_2008_01001_edges.zip")
```

If I know the list of ftp folders (or counties in this case), can I run through the ftp [site](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/01_ALABAMA/) list using the glob function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) for the zip file data *and* directory listing.

To process zip files with the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) module, you can write them to a disk file which is then passed to the `zipfile.ZipFile` constructor.
Retrieving the data is straightforward using `read()` on the file-like object returned
by `urllib2.urlopen()`.

Fetching  directories:

```
>>> files = urllib2.urlopen('ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/01_ALABAMA/').read().splitlines()
>>> for l in files[:4]: print l
... 
drwxrwsr-x    2 0        4009         4096 Nov 26  2008 01001_Autauga_County
drwxrwsr-x    2 0        4009         4096 Nov 26  2008 01003_Baldwin_County
drwxrwsr-x    2 0        4009         4096 Nov 26  2008 01005_Barbour_County
drwxrwsr-x    2 0        4009         4096 Nov 26  2008 01007_Bibb_County
>>>
```

Or, splitting for directory names:

```
>>> for l in files[:4]: print l.split()[-1]
... 
01001_Autauga_County
01003_Baldwin_County
01005_Barbour_County
01007_Bibb_County
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this explains exactly what I need to do. I'm now happily downloading a few hundred files using this.

Answer (score 5):

```
import os,urllib2
out=os.path.join("/tmp","test.zip")
url="ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/01_ALABAMA/01001_Autauga_County/tl_2008_01001_edges.zip"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
open(out,"wb").write(page.read())
```

Comment: Thanks - this explains how I need to go about saving the zipfile object, which is very useful

Answer (score 3):

Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html?highlight=urlretrieve#urllib.urlretrieve), `urlretrieve` puts the file to disk and returns a tuple `(filename, headers)`.  So the file is already saved when `urlretrieve` returns.

You can open and read the ZIP file you've retrieved with the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#module-zipfile) module of the standard library.  `glob` does not work inside zipfiles, only on normal filesystem directories.

Comment: Thanks - so if I use urllib.urlretrieve("ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2008/01_ALABAMA/01001_Autauga_County/tl_2008_01001_edges.zip", "F://") that saves it to my F-drive? Regarding my glob question, I wasn't very clear; I was wondering how I loop through a list of ftp folders on the site, rather than in a zip file.