# How to read a CSV file from a URL with Python?

Tags: python, csv, curl, output, python-2.x

when I do curl to a API call link http://example.com/passkey=wedsmdjsjmdd

```
curl 'http://example.com/passkey=wedsmdjsjmdd'
```

I get the employee output data on a csv file format, like:

```
"Steve","421","0","421","2","","","","","","","","","421","0","421","2"
```

how can parse through this using python.

I tried:

```
import csv 
cr = csv.reader(open('http://example.com/passkey=wedsmdjsjmdd',"rb"))
for row in cr:
    print row
```

but it didn't work and I got an error

`http://example.com/passkey=wedsmdjsjmdd No such file or directory:`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you access that domain directly?

Comment: you need to open the url and read it in as a big text string (see urllib/requests) , then I assume you can initialize the csv reader with a string instead of a file object, but I dont know, Ive always used it with an open filehandle.

Comment: @brbcoding, yes. I can get csv file when I put the link on the browser.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I think that your method is correct, maybe I need something like this `http://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html` but using python

Comment: FYI: the `read_csv` function in the `pandas` library (http://pandas.pydata.org/) accepts URLs.  See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41585078/562769) and [Get webpage contents with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38428249/562769). See [What if a question is an exact duplicate of the conjunction of two other questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122416/158075)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to replace `open` with [urllib.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) or [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).

e.g.

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    print row
```

This would output the following

```
Year,City,Sport,Discipline,NOC,Event,Event gender,Medal
1924,Chamonix,Skating,Figure skating,AUT,individual,M,Silver
1924,Chamonix,Skating,Figure skating,AUT,individual,W,Gold
...
```

The original question is tagged "python-2.x", but for a Python 3 implementation (which requires only minor changes) [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62614979/785213).

Comment: can you pass that to csv_reader ? I guess so ... its pretty "file-like", but I've never done it or even thought to do that

Comment: lol I dunno that I was right I was just asking ... hadn't ever seen that done before

Comment: I just assumed that it worked to be honest. Which is crazy as I have used this hundred of times. :D

Comment: I think urllib2.urlopen returns a file-like object, so you can probably just remove the `.read()`, and pass `response` to the `csv.reader`.

Comment: It does, but at least for me I don't get the excepted output. I think its a formating issue.

Comment: when I try to output the result `print cr` I get this `<_csv.reader object at 0x8e3db54>
`

Comment: @mongotop that means it is working... That shows you where the object is in memory. Looks like it only reads a line at a time, so maybe `cr.next()` inside a loop is what you are looking for. (haven't used csv reader myself...)

Comment: Like @brbcoding said. I updated my example demonstrating how to display the result.

Comment: I got this output: `['<addinfourl at 163944620 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9beca6c>>']
`

Comment: no I wasn't but when I did, I got an output but empty `
['<pre>    Method Not Allowed</pre></p><br/>                                                ']
['<br/>                                                ']
['</body>']
['</html>']
************************************
`

Comment: You did not include the address you are trying to download the data from. It looks like your web server won't allow the request. Try the csv I included in my example. And as an alternative to urllib2 you could try requests as well http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: first of all Thanks a lot for putting a life example!!1 that is very helpfule, I tried to add csv I got this error,`
    response = urllib2.urlopen(NewUrlCall+'.csv',"rb").read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 395, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 508, in http_response
http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29128/discussion-between-mongotop-and-eandersson)

Comment: please check the chat for more info,

Answer (score 148):

Using pandas it is very simple to read a csv file directly from a url

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('https://example.com/passkey=wedsmdjsjmdd')
```

This will read your data in tabular format, which will be very easy to process

Comment: This is one of the simplest approach I have come across so far!

Comment: So long as your CSV file fits into memory, this is okay.

Comment: Didn't work for me, maybe I ran out of memory. `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 33, saw 2`

Comment: is there anyway to use this with a retry, many times i get a 500 error and when i read_csv again it works. this happens a lot when i am reading from google sheets

Comment: This answer worked. The other with `csv.reader()` always gave me a `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`.

Answer (score 31):

You could do it with the requests module as well:

```
url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.iter_lines()
reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you for submitting you answer!

Comment: One question. The reader variable is a _csv.reader object. When i iterate through this object to print the contents, I get the following error. Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?). How do i read contents of the csvreader object and say load it to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Harikrishna this is probably problem in Python 3 and this case is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897029/read-csv-file-from-url-into-python-3-x-csv-error-iterator-should-return-str

Comment: This reads the whole thing into memory, not really necessary, especially if you are going to use csv.reader.  At this point, just use Pandas.

Answer (score 31):

To increase performance when downloading a large file, the below may work a bit more efficiently:

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing
import csv

url = "http://download-and-process-csv-efficiently/python.csv"

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r.iter_lines(), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        # Handle each row here...
        print row
```

By setting `stream=True` in the GET request, when we pass `r.iter_lines()` to csv.reader(), we are passing a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to csv.reader(). By doing so, we enable csv.reader() to lazily iterate over each line in the response with `for row in reader`.

This avoids loading the entire file into memory before we start processing it, drastically reducing memory overhead for large files.

Comment: This is one great solution! Thank you @The Aelfinn!

Comment: Great solution, but I had to also `import codecs` and wrap the `r.iter_lines()` within `codecs.iterdecode()` like so: `codecs.iterdecode(r.iterlines(), 'utf-8')` ... in order to solve `byte` vs `str` issues, unicode decoding problems and universal new line problems.

Comment: I was looking for a solution like this, with requests.

Comment: I like this solution a lot

Answer (score 30):

This question is tagged `python-2.x` so it didn't seem right to tamper with the original question, or the accepted answer. However, Python 2 is now unsupported, and this question still has good google juice for "python csv urllib", so here's an updated Python 3 solution.

It's now necessary to decode `urlopen`'s response (in bytes) into a valid local encoding, so the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283926/785213) has to be modified slightly:

```py
import csv, urllib.request

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
cr = csv.reader(lines)

for row in cr:
    print(row)
```

Note the extra line beginning with `lines =`, the fact that `urlopen` is now in the `urllib.request` module, and `print` of course requires parentheses.

It's hardly advertised, but yes, `csv.reader` *can* read from a list of strings.

And since someone else mentioned pandas, here's a pandas rendition that displays the CSV in a console-friendly output:

```bash
python3 -c 'import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv")
print(df.to_string())'
```

Pandas is *not* a lightweight library, though. If you don't *need* the things that pandas provides, or if startup time is important (*e.g.* you're writing a command line utility or any other program that needs to load quickly), I'd advise that you stick with the standard library functions.

Comment: Thank you @ThedudeAbides for providing an updated solution!

Comment: Just want to add that `import pandas` alone will be an order of magnitude slower than any other solution on this page. So don't go `pip install pandas` JUST because you see that you can do a cool one-liner with it; it also brings in numpy as a dependency, and it's all downhill from there. Same goes for `import requests`, although not to such a degree.

Answer (score 10):

```
import pandas as pd
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juliencohensolal/BankMarketing/master/rawData/bank-additional-full.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url,sep=";") # use sep="," for coma separation. 
data.describe()
```

[image]

Comment: With python 3.8: Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'pandas' has no attribute 'describe'

Answer (score 4):

I am also using this approach for csv files (Python 3.6.9):

```py
import csv
import io
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
buff = io.StringIO(r.text)
dr = csv.DictReader(buff)
for row in dr:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions didn't work with Python3, I got all the "famous" error messages, like `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)` and `_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`. So I was a bit stuck here.

My mistake here, was that I used `response.text` while `response` is a `requests.models.Response` class, while I should have used `response.content` instead (as the first error suggested), so I was able to decode its UTF-8 correctly and split lines afterwards. So here is my solution:

```
import csv
import reqto

response = reqto.get("https://example.org/utf8-data.csv")
# Do some error checks to avoid bad results
if response.ok and len(response.content) > 0:
    reader = csv.DictReader(response.content.decode('utf-8').splitlines(), dialect='unix')
    for row in reader:
        print(f"DEBUG: row={row}")
```

The above example gives me already a `dict` back with each row. But with leading `#` for each dict key, which I may have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

what you were trying to do with the curl command was to download the file to your local hard drive(HD). You however need to specify a path on HD

```
curl http://example.com/passkey=wedsmdjsjmdd -o ./example.csv
cr = csv.reader(open('./example.csv',"r"))
for row in cr:
    print row
```