# Read .csv file from URL into Python 3.x - _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Tags: python, url, csv, python-3.x

I've been struggling with this simple problem for too long, so I thought I'd ask for help. I am trying to read a list of journal articles from National Library of Medicine ftp site into Python 3.3.2 (on Windows 7). The journal articles are in a .csv file.

I have tried the following code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

url = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/file_list.csv"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(ftpstream)
data = [row for row in csvfile]
```

It results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
data = [row for row in csvfile]
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <listcomp>
data = [row for row in csvfile]
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I presume I should be working with strings not bytes? Any help with the simple problem, and an explanation as to what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem relies on `urllib` returning bytes. As a proof, you can try to download the csv file with your browser and opening it as a regular file and the problem is gone.

A similar problem was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings).

It can be solved decoding bytes to strings with the appropriate encoding. For example:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

url = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/file_list.csv"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8'))  # with the appropriate encoding 
data = [row for row in csvfile]
```

The last line could also be: `data = list(csvfile)` which can be easier to read.

By the way, since the csv file is very big, it can slow and memory-consuming. Maybe it would be preferable to use a generator.

**EDIT:**
Using codecs as proposed by Steven Rumbalski so it's not necessary to read the whole file to decode. Memory consumption reduced and speed increased.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import codecs

url = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/file_list.csv"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(ftpstream, 'utf-8'))
for line in csvfile:
    print(line)  # do something with line
```

Note that the list is not created either for the same reason.

Comment: +1.  However, something feels wrong about having to read all the data before decoding it.  Does Python 3 offer anything that allows this to be done as a generator?

Comment: Figured it out.  The Python 3 way to stream this is to use `codecs.iterdecode`.

Comment: Added a version of the snippet using codecs to make use of generators.

Comment: with `responseHeader = response.info()` you can even get the response header from where you can get the correct encoding e.g. with `encoding = responseHeader['Content-Type'].split(';')[1].split('=')[1]` which you can use for decoding the response `response.read().decode(encoding)`, so you don't have to hardcode the encoding and react to different encodings

Answer (score 16):

Even though there is already an accepted answer, I thought I'd add to the body of knowledge by showing how I achieved something similar using the `requests` package (which is sometimes seen as an alternative to `urlib.request`).

The basis of using `codecs.itercode()` to solve the original problem is still the same as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18897408/2105711).

```
import codecs
from contextlib import closing
import csv
import requests

url = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/file_list.csv"

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(r.iter_lines(), 'utf-8'))
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Here we also see the use of *streaming* provided through the `requests` package in order to avoid having to load the entire file over the network into memory first (which could take long if the file is large).

I thought it might be useful since it helped me, as I was using `requests` rather than `urllib.request` in Python 3.6.

Some of the ideas (e.g using `closing()`) are picked from this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677619/2105711)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using `requests` package and `csv`.
The response from post request was type `bytes`.
In order to user `csv` library, first I a stored them as a string file in memory (in my case the size was small), decoded utf-8.

```py
import io
import csv
import requests

response = requests.post(url, data)

# response.content is something like: 
# b'"City","Awb","Total"\r\n"Bucuresti","6733338850003","32.57"\r\n'    
csv_bytes = response.content

# write in-memory string file from bytes, decoded (utf-8)
str_file = io.StringIO(csv_bytes.decode('utf-8'), newline='\n')
    
reader = csv.reader(str_file)
for row_list in reader:
    print(row_list)

# Once the file is closed,
# any operation on the file (e.g. reading or writing) will raise a ValueError
str_file.close()
```

Printed something like:

```sh
['City', 'Awb', 'Total']
['Bucuresti', '6733338850003', '32.57']
```

Answer (score -1):

`urlopen` will return a `urllib.response.addinfourl` instance for an ftp request.

> For ftp, file, and data urls and requests explicity handled by legacy
>   URLopener and FancyURLopener classes, this function returns a
>   urllib.response.addinfourl object which can work as context manager...

```
>>> urllib2.urlopen(url)
<addinfourl at 48868168L whose fp = <addclosehook at 48777416L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000002E52B88>>>
```

At this point `ftpstream` is a file *like* object, using `.read()` would return the contents however `csv.reader` requires an iterable in this case:

Defining a generator like so:

```
def to_lines(f):
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        yield line
        line = f.readline()
```

We  can create our csv reader like so:

```
reader = csv.reader(to_lines(ftps))
```

And with a url

```
url = "http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v41r1/topic/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/CIsImportMinimumSample.csv"
```

The code:

```
for row in reader: print row
```

Prints

```
>>> 
['simpleci']
['SCI.APPSERVER']
['SRM_SaaS_ES', 'MXCIImport', 'AddChange', 'EN']
['CI_CINUM']
['unique_identifier1']
['unique_identifier2']
```

Comment: Incorrect.  `StringIO` is a Python 2 module.  Answer needs to be for Python 3.  This is particularly important because of how Python 3 handles strings.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I assume using http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.StringIO would be alright then?

Comment: `StringIO` does not accept bytes: `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski see my updated answer, which doesn't read in the whole file or use stringIO