# How can I get arff.loadarff to work with urllib.request to read a arff file from a URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, arff

Any ideas on best way to get `arff.loadarff` to work from a URL? I am trying to read an arff file from the following URL [using Python 3.7]: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff

I have tried a few methods and the central problem is getting urllib.request to return a file or file-like object so that arff.loadarff can recognize it and read it properly.

Here is some of what I have tried and the results:

```
from scipy.io import arff
import urllib.request

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data, meta = arff.loadarff(response)
```

This gives an error TypeError because urlopen returns a response object.

I also tried to follow the solutions in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897029/read-csv-file-from-url-into-python-3-x-csv-error-iterator-should-return-str):

```
from scipy.io import arff
import urllib.request
import codecs

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data, meta = arff.loadarff(codecs.iterdecode(ftpstream, 'utf-8'))
```

but this also gives a TypeError because the codecs.iterdecode returns a generator. And this one:

```
from scipy.io import arff
import urllib.request

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data, meta = arff.loadarff(ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

This accesses the file as a string but returns the full arff file as the file name and I get an error that the filename is too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. `loadarff()` needs a text file-like object which neither `urlopen()` nor the result of `decode()` fulfils. So the way to do is to wrap the text string content into a file-like object using `io.StringIO()`:

```
from scipy.io import arff
import urllib.request
import io # for io.StringIO()

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data, meta = arff.loadarff(io.StringIO(ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8')))
```

A file-like object here means something `x` that can do `x.read()` and returns a string, just like the file object returned by `open(filename)`