# How to save many CSV files from URL

Tags: python, url, csv

I have many CSV files that I need to get from a URL.  I found this reference: [How to read a CSV file from a URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283799/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-a-url-python)

It does almost the thing I want, but I don't want to go through Python to read the CSV and then have to save it.  I just want to directly save the CSV file from the URL to my hard drive.

I have no problem with for loops and cycling through my URLs.  It is simply a matter of saving the CSV file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is save a csv, then I wouldn't suggest using python at all. In fact this is more of a unix question. Making the assumption here that you're working on some kind of *nix system I would suggest just using `wget`. For instance:

```
wget http://someurl/path/to/file.csv
```

You can run this command directly from python like so:

```
import subprocess
bashCommand = lambda url, filename: "wget -O %s.csv %s" % (filename, url)
save_locations = {'http://someurl/path/to/file.csv': 'test.csv'}
for url, filename in save_locations.items():
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand(url, filename).split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
```