# Downloading csv file from a website using python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following website [yahoo finance](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EBSESN&a=03&b=3&c=1997&d=10&e=4&f=2015&g=d). I want to set a date range on that page for e.g April 3rd 1997 to 4th November 2015. Once I set the date range I get a link to download the file as `csv` on that page, below the tables. I want to download the csv file. But I want all of this to be done programmatically. How do I achieve this using python.

Comment: You didn't found anything using google?

Answer (score 8):

This might be helpful :

```
import requests
import shutil
def callme():
    url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EBSESN&a=03&b=3&c=1997&d=10&e=4&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv"
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False,stream=True)
    if r.status_code!=200:
        print "Failure!!"
        exit()
    else:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        with open("file1.csv", 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
        print "Success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    callme()
```

How to get this URL ?
You can get the list of API calls in any website by right click-> Inspect Element ->Network.
Now when you make any request from browser, it will list out all the API calls.

You can split the date according to your need and pass it in the URL. You need to do some research about how Yahoo passes the date in URL.

Edit 1: This script will run over HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate the URL to download the CSV you want, for example from `April 3, 1997` to `Nov 4, 2015` you can set the URL to

```
https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EBSESN&a=[month]&b=[date]&c=[year]&d=[month]&e=[date]&f=[year]&g=[daily/weekly/monthly/dividends_only]
```

Month can be `00`, `01`, `02`, `03`, `04` up to `11` (Note: Month start from 00)

Date can start from `01` to `31`

Year is in format `'yyyy'`

For the daily -> `d`, for weekly -> `w`, for monthly -> `m`, for dividends only -> `v`

---

Now you have the URL, then to download the CSV you can just use 
link: `URL=URL&ignore=.csv`

```
import urllib
url = '[URL]'
csv = urllib.urlopen(url).read() # returns type 'str'
with open('file.csv', 'w') as fx: # str, hence mode 'w'
fx.write(csv)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps, but when i am trying to open a url, which requires login acess, I got 'HTTP Error 403: Forbidden', how do i overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). There are some other lightweight tools too, that can find by google.

Update:
It seems you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283926/1334399).

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this using a simple python script? I could construct the URL. Once I load the URL I get the html page. How do I download the csv file from the link on that page.?

Comment: see the update, using urllib2 you can do that