# getting csv file from the url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download a csv file which is on web portal, when doing it manually we login to the url and click on <kbd>Download CSV</kbd> button then it prompts for saving. we are using python3

I am trying to do this via python scripting, when we execute this script we get the the html page with the name `Download CSV`, when we click on that we get a csv file through that.

```
import urllib.request
import requests


session = requests.session()
playload = {'j_username':'avinash.reddy', 'j_password':'password'}
r = session.post('https://url_of_the_portal/auth/login','data=playload')
r = session.get('URL_of_the_page_where_the_csv_file_exiests')
url='https://url_of_the_portal/review/download/bm_sis'
print ('done')
urllib.request.urlretrieve (url, "Download CSV")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this + your login creds.

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    print row
```

Else...

```
url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.iter_lines()
reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=',')
```

Else...

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing
import csv

url = "http://download-and-process-csv-efficiently/python.csv"

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r.iter_lines(), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        # Handle each row here...
        print row
```

[How to read a CSV file from a URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283799/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-a-url-with-python)