# facebook android api getUsername returns null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get person's user name with facebook graph user object. It gives firstname, lastname and other details correctly but gives null when I call getUserName().

```
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {

                //facebook authentication done.
                //Disable login button

                Log.d("From FB", user.getFirstName());
                Log.d("From FB", user.getLastName());
                Log.d("From FB", user.getId());
                Log.d("From FB", user.getProperty("email").toString());
                Log.d("From FB", user.getUsername());//gives null
```

Is there any other way to get the person's userName? Please let me know how to get person's user name.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428498/get-username-field-in-facebook-graph-api-2-0

Comment: I am bit afraid of making changes in the code now, is there any way in graph 2.x api to get profile pic

Comment: You can use id to generate userpage link. `'https://www.facebook.com/' + user.getId()`. Does it works for you?

Comment: yes doubleui, that worked thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username field is no longer available with the Graph API v2.0. Refer

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/#fields

Comment: thanks mukesh, can you please help me how i can get user's profile pic in this case?

Comment: just replace your fb_id and height and width of picture in this url http://graph.facebook.com/facebookId/picture?width=picWidth&height=picHeight