# How to get username from Facebook ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the Internet there are a few topics about this problem, but I have not found any complex solution. Therefore, I would like to ask you for help.

I need to change facebook id to username.

When you type web site like this:

`http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=4` (num 4 is FB id), it will give you `http://www.facebook.com/zuck`, which is Mark Zuckerberg's profile.

On this principle I need to find out who a id is.

I have typed id `4` a got it is `zuck`.

But I need it for more ids, so it would take a lot of time do it manually. Please help me, how I can do it.

Comment: This worked for me - https://findmyfbid.in/ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have an ID of that particular user, then just add it on this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>
```

Simple example:

```
function get_basic_info($id) {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id;
    $info = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    return $info;
}

$id = 4;
$user = get_basic_info($id);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
```

This should basically yield:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [first_name] => Mark
    [gender] => male
    [last_name] => Zuckerberg
    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/zuck
    [locale] => en_US
    [name] => Mark Zuckerberg
    [username] => zuck
)
```

Then you could just call it like a normal array:

```
echo $user['username'];
```

Sidenote: Why not use the PHP SDK instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

Comment: Which will stop working at 4/30/2015 when API v1.0 is removed

Comment: the php sdk is way too heavy for such an easy task, imho. but the answer is correct, so +1 for you :)

Comment: @luschn yeah good point too, might be cumbersome for such a simple intent

Comment: The username field is not availalbe any more now

Answer (score 3):

As the username is NO more available from Graph API endpoint `/user-id` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643117/248616), I propose another workaround here (but with Python code)

In brief, we open the page at **fb.com/USER_ID** and scrape the username from it

```
#get html of a page via pure python ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23565355/248616
import requests
r = requests.get('http://fb.com/%s' % FB_USER_ID) #open profile page of the facebook user
r.raise_for_status()
html = r.content

#search string with regex ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667014/248616
import re
# m = re.search('meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/([^?]+)\?', html)
m = re.search('a class="profileLink" href="([^"]+)"', html)
href = m.group(1) #will be https://www.facebook.com/$FB_USER_NAME on 201705.24
username = href.split('/')[-1]
print(href)
print(username)
```

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, don´t do that. there is no situation where you would need the real id or the username anymore anyway.

Comment: @luschn My app needs to create a profile URL link for the FB user...that seems like a real use case to me.

Comment: "my app needs it" is not a use case ;) - why exactly would your app need it? why would people need to go to a profile url of facebook in your app? - btw, the api reference says that there is a "link" field for users. did you try this?

Comment: @luschn link field is also deprecated I suppose?

Comment: I am not sure, I just tried it using graph API explored and didn't got user profile link

Comment: Also, There can be various situation where you would need the real id or username. Like I want to create a Dating App just like facebook where you would get a match if both the users have added themselves. Typically user would add a username of the people who they want to date and if two user have added each other username, then there would be a match

Answer (score 2):

As of October 2019, The only way it is possible is to request for user_links in request and permissions

[image]

And then pass it in a scope, something like this

```
scope: ['user_link']
```